# How to import CSV data from Google Drive/Google Sheets into BigQuery correctly

Tags: csv, google-drive-api, google-bigquery

I'm trying to import a CSV file placed in Google Drive into BigQuery and fail. I get an error `Error while reading table, error message: CSV table encountered too many errors, giving up`.

I guess to know, what caused an error. The CSV file contains strings in the columns A, B and D, integer in column C, and float in columns E and F. Delimiter is the tab, `\t`.

While the CSV file contains data like on the image 1:

[image: So looks the data in Excel]

If i look at the file preview in Google Drive, i see broken numbers, like on the image 2: However, if i download file directly from the GDrive and open it with Notepad++, the file exactly as expected: numbers with commas as decimal sign and tab as column delimiter...

[image]

On creating the BigQuery table i add columns manually and assign to them field types too. For columns containing numbers i tested any combination of `integer`, `float` and `numeric` - always the same error.

**Q**: how should i format the CSV file to make the import possible?

Here is a sample of the file:

```
Domain  Keywords    RP  Brand   SI  SiBerechnet
example.de  accura versicherung 1   accura  293,9   0,00244913
example.de  accura versicherung erfahrung   1   accura  63,9    0,00053249
example.de  accura versicherung für wohnmobile  1   accura  43,9    0,00036583
example.de  accura versicherung keine wohnmobile mehr   1   accura  53,9    0,00044916
example.de  accura versicherungsmakler  1   accura  83,9    0,00069916
example.de  accura versicherung test    1   accura  43,9    0,00036583
example.de  accura versicherung wohnmobil   1   accura  73,9    0,00061582
example.de  accura wohnmobilversicherung erfahrungen    1   accura  73,9    0,00061582
example.de  aufgaben innendienst versicherung   75  non brand   0,133333333 0,00000111
example.de  aufgaben versicherung innendienst   59  non brand   0,169491525 0,00000141
example.de  basler versicherung kfz telefonnummer   98  basler  0,102040816 0,00000085
example.de  basler versicherung kundenservice   96  basler  0,104166667 0,00000087
example.de  basler wohnmobilversicherung    8   basler  3,86    0,00003217
example.de  bergungskosten unfallversicherung   37  non brand   0,810810811 0,00000676
example.de  berufsunfähigkeitsversicherung bei bürojob  84  non brand   0,238095238 0,00000198
example.de  berufsunfähigkeitsversicherung bürojob  83  non brand   1,084337349 0,00000904
example.de  betriebshaftpflicht für hausmeisterservice  87  non brand   0,114942529 0,00000096
example.de  betriebshaftpflicht für hausverwalter   29  non brand   1,034482759 0,00000862
example.de  betriebshaftpflicht hausmeister 87  non brand   0,114942529 0,00000096
example.de  betriebshaftpflicht hausverwalter   26  non brand   0,384615385 0,00000321
example.de  betriebsunterbrechungsversicherung freiberufler 46  non brand   0,217391304 0,00000181
example.de  braucht eine krankenschwester eine diensthaftpflichtversicherung    15  non brand   2,706666667 0,00002256
example.de  campingfahrzeug versicherung    39  non brand   1,025641026 0,00000855
example.de  dienst haftpflicht  99  non brand   0,303030303 0,00000253
example.de  diensthaftpflicht öffentlicher dienst   55  non brand   0,545454545 0,00000455
example.de  diensthaftpflichtversicherung   57  non brand   22,80701754 0,00019006
example.de  dienst haftpflichtversicherung  84  non brand   0,238095238 0,00000198
example.de  diensthaftpflichtversicherung beamte    90  non brand   0,555555556 0,00000463
example.de  diensthaftpflichtversicherung für soldaten  28  non brand   0,357142857 0,00000298
example.de  diensthaftpflichtversicherung kosten    80  non brand   0,5 0,00000417
example.de  diensthaftpflichtversicherung öffentlicher dienst   51  non brand   0,980392157 0,00000817
example.de  diensthaftpflichtversicherung öffentlicher dienst angestellte   63  non brand   0,158730159 0,00000132
example.de  diensthaftpflichtversicherung polizei   69  non brand   0,724637681 0,00000604
example.de  diensthaftpflichtversicherung soldaten  26  non brand   0,769230769 0,00000641
example.de  einbauküche hausrat oder gebäude scheidung  31  non brand   0,64516129  0,00000538
example.de  einbauküche hausratversicherung oder gebäudeversicherung    12  non brand   2,643333333 0,00002203
```

Comment: Could you possibly share a snippet (e.g. 5 lines) of the raw data file and obfuscate/redact any sensitive fields? It's hard to work with screenshots and different software formats/munges in different ways.

Comment: Are you able to look into the BigQuery job history for a more detailed error? This will usually give more specifics on where the error was encountered and what kind of failure you may be dealing with.

Comment: @GrahamPolley i edited my post with a file sample

Comment: i probably found the workout to correctly import the file - i replaced comma as decimal limiter to point. But this isn't very handy - maybe somebody knows, how to import such data with comma as decimal limiter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've copied your data to a Google Sheets, then I exported it with the tab as the field delimiter and I was able to load the data by specifying the [field delimiter](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#csv-options) and I didn't have any issues as the table was created (However the numbers didn't take the comma as the decimal delimiter as it's [used as a thousand separator always](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129992574#comment4)). Thus, I imported all the columns as Strings then I applied a [REGEX_REPLACE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#regexp_replace) like the following:

```
SELECT CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(siberechnet, ",", ".") as numeric) as new_col FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

To use the decimal numbers properly

Hope it helps for your use-case.

Answer (score 2):

What happens often is that the language settings on the drive sheets are different and are throwing around the "." and ",".

You can see/change this in File -> spreadsheet settings

Comment: Changing the language setting from German to US helped me to correctly import a csv with numbers with decimal points. Thanks!